# Vertically center different font-sized spans on one line?

Tags: html, css

I have something like the following:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <span id="small">I want to be vertically centered!!!</span>
  <span id="big">BIG</span>
</div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gjf1neeq/2/

How can I vertically center the first span?

Comment: You can use display: flex on the parent div. https://jsfiddle.net/o7d31ofd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest both `vertical-align: middle` as well as setting a `line-height`.

While the `line-height` isn't strictly needed, it is a useful means to determine the height over which you'd like the text to be centered.  For example, if you knew you wanted the height of the space to be 100px, you could set the `line-height: 100px;`, and it would occupy 100px, and both lines of text would be centered in that space.

```
span#small,
span#big {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/vpe65a8m/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Giving the spans `display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;` will vertically center them with respect to each other.

```css
span {display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;}
span#big {font-size: 200%;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <span id="small">I want to be vertically centered!!!</span>
  <span id="big">BIG</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with flexbox:

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#big {
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/686rusgn/1/